# Uable to access to localhost:8080 after upgrading NodeJS to 8.1.4

Tags: node.js, selenium, nightwatch.js

Our development group is starting a new React project and I have been trying to use Nightwatch + Selenium to do the e2e testing. I got it to work when running everything using **NodeJS 6.9.4**. Now we have been forced to upgrade NodeJS to 8.1.4 and I'm facing an issue that is stopping me to proceed with testing. When using Selenium with Chrome as browser, I keep getting a 'This site can't be reached' message (but the page can be accessed if I open manually a Chrome window. Any idea what can be going on? Here you have the test result log and my nightwatch.conf.js

***Test Result:***

```
INFO Request: GET /wd/hub/session/fc36e7a7-4909-4dfd-a853-6d769accb085/element/0/text 
  - data: 
  - headers:  {"Accept":"application/json"}
INFO Response 200 GET /wd/hub/session/fc36e7a7-4909-4dfd-a853-6d769accb085/element/0/text (16ms) { state: 'success',
  sessionId: 'fc36e7a7-4909-4dfd-a853-6d769accb085',
  hCode: 972983271,
  value: 'This site can’t be reached',
  class: 'org.openqa.selenium.remote.Response',
  status: 0 }
```

***Nightwatch Conf***

```
const SCREENSHOT_PATH = "./screenshots/";
const BIN_PATH = './node_modules/nightwatch/bin/';
``
// we use a nightwatch.conf.js file so we can include comments and helper functions
module.exports = {
    "src_folders": [
        "__tests__/e2e/specs"// Where you are storing your Nightwatch e2e tests
    ],
    "output_folder": "./reports", // reports (test outcome) output by nightwatch
    "selenium": { // downloaded by selenium-download module (see readme)
        "start_process": false, // tells nightwatch to start/stop the selenium process
        "server_path": "./node_modules/nightwatch/bin/selenium.jar",
        "host": "127.0.0.1",
        "port": 4444, // standard selenium port
        "cli_args": { // chromedriver is downloaded by selenium-download (see readme)
            "webdriver.chrome.driver" : "./node_modules/nightwatch/bin/chromedriver"
        }
    },
    "test_settings": {
        "default": {
            "screenshots": {
                "enabled": true, // if you want to keep screenshots
                "path": './screenshots' // save screenshots here
            },
            "globals": {
                "waitForConditionTimeout": 5000 // sometimes internet is slow so wait.
            },
            "desiredCapabilities": { // use Chrome as the default browser for tests
                "browserName": "chrome",
                "javascriptEnabled": true, // turn off to test progressive enhancement
                "chromeOptions" : {
                  "args": ['--disable-web-security', 'no-sandbox', '--disable-async-dns']
                }
            }
        },
        "chrome": {
            "desiredCapabilities": {
                "browserName": "chrome",
                "javascriptEnabled": true, // turn off to test progressive enhancement
                "chromeOptions" : {
                  "args": ['--disable-web-security', 'no-sandbox', '--disable-async-dns']
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "params": {
        "baseUrl": "http://localhost:8080/",
    }
}
```

Sorry for having the files attached instead of expanded on the comment but tho I have been using StackOverflow for a long time, this is my first request. StackOverflow

Answer (score 0):

Apparently my localhost is not visible to the Selenium Chrome that is running. Needed to make my localhost accesible from outside my machine in order to get this running